# joining results after making parallel calls using spring async

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I'm using spring @Async to make parallel calls to the same method/backend. Is there a clean way to join their results in a list? This is the pseudo code i came up with to make the calls/merge the result, but I'm not sure it's the cleanest way.

```
List<Future<String>> futureStringList = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
for(each backend call){
           Future<String> futureString = backend.retrieve();
           futureStringList.add(futureString);
}


List<String> actualStringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(!futureStringList.isEmpty()){
           for(Future<String> futureString: futureStringList){
                          if(futureString.isDone()){
                                         actualStringList.add(futureString.get());
                                         futureStringList.remove(futureString);
                          }
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Future.get()` is a blocking call, so you can actually loop over your `Future` list and you know that, at the end of the loop, all your futures are finished.

```
List<Future<String>> futureStringList = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
for(each backend call){
    Future<String> futureString = backend.retrieve();
    futureStringList.add(futureString);
}

List<String> actualStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Future<String> stringFuture : futureStringList) {
  actualStringList.add(stringFuture.get()); // blocking call
}

// all your Strings are retrieved at this point
```

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid blocking the for loop, which is why I put the while loop around it.

Comment: Why? In your code, the thread is stuck in the loop as well and eat a lot of CPU (unnecessarily).